# Multiple values in WHERE clause using sqldf in R

Tags: sqldf

I am trying to query multiple values in the WHERE clause, using sqldf in R.  I have the following query, however, it continues to throw an error.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
sqldf("SELECT amount
from df
where category = 'description' and 'original description'")
```

> ERROR: <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

Comment: I was also interested in using the "LIKE" operator also.  For example,

sqldf("SELECT amount
from df
where category LIKE '%description%' and LIKE category '%original description'")

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use in condition

sqldf("SELECT amount
from df
where category in ('description','original description')")

If you want to use like operator, you need to use OR instead of AND.(not sure what other entries are in the category, if you don't have any other category that has "description" in its name, the following might be enough

sqldf("SELECT amount from df where category LIKE 'descriptio%'")

Answer (score 0):

You need to define each where clause explicitly, so

`SELECT amount FROM df  WHERE category = 'description' OR category = 'original description'`

You can pass in multiple values, it's done with the IN operator:

`SELECT amount FROM df WHERE category IN ( 'description', 'original description' )`